# Why $con has no value in funciones.php

Tags: php, mysql, apache

This is musica.php

```
               $sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT url_img,nombre FROM discos");
                $sentencia->execute();
                while ($fila = $sentencia->fetch()) {
                   print '<div class="disco"><img src="'.$fila["url_img"].'">'
                           .$fila["nombre"]
                           . '</div>';

                }
               cargarDiscos();
             ?>
```

This works fine here, but when I try to use the cargarDiscos() function seems to fail and its the same code. This is funciones.php with the cargarDiscos() function who has the same code as musica.php

```
<?php
     include 'conexion.php'; // El compilador coga el archivo y lo incluya   

     function cargarDiscos(){
            $sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT url_img,nombre FROM discos");
                    $sentencia->execute();
                    while ($fila = $sentencia->fetch()) {
                       print '<div class="disco"><img src="'.$fila["url_img"].'">'
                               .$fila["nombre"]
                               . '</div>';

                    }
     }
?>
```

funciones.php  has the database conexion include. And this is my error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: con in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\spotifake\funciones.php on line 5
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on
>   null in C:\xampp\htdocs\spotifake\funciones.php:5 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\spotifake\musica.php(42): cargarDiscos() #1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\spotifake\funciones.php on line 5

Comment: A function is a different scope, you need to pass the `$con` variable into the function (or use globals, but don't do that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass $con as a parameter like this:

```
<?php
     include 'conexion.php'; // El compilador coga el archivo y lo incluya   

     function cargarDiscos($c){
            $sentencia = $c->prepare("SELECT url_img,nombre FROM discos");
                    $sentencia->execute();
                    while ($fila = $sentencia->fetch()) {
                       print '<div class="disco"><img src="'.$fila["url_img"].'">'
                               .$fila["nombre"]
                               . '</div>';

                    }
     }
?>
```

and then call the function like this:

```
cargarDiscos($con);
```

If this is not working, just double check that 'conexion.php' is called with the right path, it depends where second script is located.

Saludos!

Comment: Also did this too, fixed the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you should declare con as global

```
function cargarDiscos(){
      global $con; // <<<<<<<<<<<
            $sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT url_img,nombre FROM discos");
                    $sentencia->execute();
                    while ($fila = $sentencia->fetch()) {
                       print '<div class="disco"><img src="'.$fila["url_img"].'">'
                               .$fila["nombre"]
                               . '</div>';

                    }
     }
```

Comment: Making it global fixed it. Thank you Ilyas.